# Can't change icons for subitems in NavigationView

Tags: android, submenu, navigationview

I'm trying to do checkbox behaviour in a `NavigationView`

With no subitems (all top level menu items) I can happily change the icons using the following code:

```
    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    Boolean boolObj = mMenuToggleMap.get(menuItem.getItemId());
                    boolean state = boolObj == null ? true : boolObj.booleanValue();
                    state = !state;
                    if(state) menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_check_off_holo_light);
                    else      menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.btn_check_on_holo_light);
                    mMenuToggleMap.put(menuItem.getItemId(), state);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

menu.xml:

```
        <item
            android:id="@+id/books"
            android:title="@string/books"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/cddvds"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light"
            android:title="@string/cddvds"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

As you can see:

[image]

However, as soon as I change my XML like so:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/categorySubHeader"
    android:title="@string/categories">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/books"
            android:title="@string/books"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/cddvds"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light"
            android:title="@string/cddvds"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

I find that the icons no longer change (even though the code in the listener is still being called). Can anyone give me a clue as to why these items aren't updating?

I'm wondering if an `invalidateMenuOptions()` can be called on the NavigationView or a `notifyDataSetChanged()` functionality can be called on the backing data?

Comment: check my updated answer. If I am not late .. lolzz

Comment: Edited answer is working with sub item also ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all make sure that your both item should not be subitem.** Because I also face same issue that changing the icon of subitem is not working properly.

So your XML should look like.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="ng.edu.binghamuni.bhu.ui.activity.HomeActivity">

     <item
            android:id="@+id/books"
            android:title="@string/books"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/cddvds"
            android:icon="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light"
            android:title="@string/cddvds"
            app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

On your Navigation click do the following code.

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.books:
                    menuItem.setIcon((isBookChecked)?R.drawable.btn_check_off_holo_light:R.drawable.btn_check_on_holo_light);
                    isBookChecked = !isBookChecked;
                    break;
                case R.id.cddvds:
                    menuItem.setIcon((isCdDVDChecked)?R.drawable.btn_check_off_holo_light:R.drawable.btn_check_on_holo_light);
                    isCdDVDChecked = !isCdDVDChecked;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Just create two variable `isBookChecked` and `isCdDVDChecked`  globally to maintain checked state manully.

**[Update-------------------/////]**

I spent some time for changing icon of subitem. **finally i did it**. But currently **it's tricky solution**.
Becuase month ago i have report a bug: 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176300, that we can't add dynamic menu to navigation view. and i think this is also chain of that bug (Update UI issue) .

So,for solution do following on your navigation click..

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            // change the icon as you need
            menuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background));

            // here is the trick. Resetting the title of top level item.
            navView.getMenu().getItem(0).setTitle(navView.getMenu().getItem(0).getTitle());
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Actully when we are changing the icon using setIcon() method. the icon is changing but the issue is that it will not updating UI. **So resetting the title of top level item will update UI**. I hope it helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I said, works fine if the items are top level items (as you have in your example). I only find a problem when the items are subitems (they are nested within another item like <item><menu><item></item></menu></item>). It's at this stage that the entire set seem to respond as one - and this is the functionality I require.

Comment: So it is being caused by a bug then? I have seen some answer knocking around which involve finding a "notify" method by reflection and calling that but have had to switch to a manual approach rather than use these built in icons.

Comment: Yes it is a bug ... and the bug is solved and marked as a future release. So we it will not happen in a future library. But for now you can apply my tricky solution ..

Comment: As I can't test, I'll set it as fixed unless I come back to it implement it and find otherwise. Thanks!